# Python password generator that creates a new password on user input

Tags: python, passwords

I'm just starting to learn Python and have started a small project for our Service Desk, a password generator.  It works, however I'd like it to take a users input and create another password.  I've done a lot of searching and have found tons of password generators, I've figured out how to repeat one password, but not how to generate a new passowrd on input.  My code is below that will repeat a password on input.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    import random

alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
pw_length = 6
mypw = ""

for i in range(pw_length):
    next_index = random.randrange(len(alphabet))
    mypw = mypw + alphabet[next_index]

# replace 1 or 2 characters with a number
for i in range(random.randrange(1,3)):
    replace_index = random.randrange(len(mypw)//2)
    mypw = mypw[0:replace_index] + str(random.randrange(10)) + 
mypw[replace_index+1:]

# replace 1 or 2 letters with an uppercase letter
for i in range(random.randrange(1,3)):
    replace_index = random.randrange(len(mypw)//2,len(mypw))
    mypw = mypw[0:replace_index] + mypw[replace_index].upper() + 
mypw[replace_index+1:]

print("Your password is" + (mypw))
inp = input()
while inp != "":
    print(mypw)
    inp = input()
```

Comment: Be specific about your question...What is it you want?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, I want this to create a new random password with user input, example, N for new password, X to exit.

Now that I've put it out there, I think I may need to make a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to repeat the password generation, by putting everything into the while-loop, or better, write a function to generate one password and call this function inside the while-loop:

```
import random

alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
pw_length = 6

def generate_password(pw_length):
    mypw = ""
    for i in range(pw_length):
        next_index = random.randrange(len(alphabet))
        mypw = mypw + alphabet[next_index]

    # replace 1 or 2 characters with a number
    for i in range(random.randrange(1,3)):
        replace_index = random.randrange(len(mypw)//2)
        mypw = mypw[0:replace_index] + str(random.randrange(10)) + 
    mypw[replace_index+1:]

    # replace 1 or 2 letters with an uppercase letter
    for i in range(random.randrange(1,3)):
        replace_index = random.randrange(len(mypw)//2,len(mypw))
        mypw = mypw[0:replace_index] + mypw[replace_index].upper() + 
    mypw[replace_index+1:]
    return mypw

while True:
    print("Your password is", generate_password(pw_length))
    inp = input()
    if not inp:
        break
```

or a slightly optimized version:

```
import string
import random

def generate_password(pw_length):
    charsets = []
    # take 1 or 2 numbers
    for i in range(random.randrange(1,3)):
        charsets.append(string.digits)
    # take 1 or 2 uppercase
    for i in range(random.randrange(1,3)):
        charsets.append(string.ascii_uppercase)
    # fill up with lowercase up to pw_length
    while len(charsets) < pw_length:
        charsets.append(string.ascii_lowercase)
    # generate password of charsets
    random.shuffle(charsets)
    return ''.join(random.choice(cs) for cs in charsets)

while True:
    print("Your password is", generate_password(pw_length))
    inp = input()
    if not inp:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately can not comment with my rating, but i guess hashing the input will work? since it generates a 'random' string.
Also hashing is an okay practice to store passwords.

```
def Generate_Password():
    input_ = input('please enter your password: ')
#i saw you have a limit of length 6, but you can tweak it
    if len(input_) > 6:
        print ('Max length for a pssword is 6')
    hashPassword = hashlib.sha3_256(b'{input_}').hexdigest()
    return (hashPassword)
```

Answer (score 0):

Generating password
very password need combination of all character

class password:
    def **init**(self):
        #self.choice = choice
        self.menu =  {1: 'generate pass',3: 'exit'}
    def main(self):
        for x, y in self.menu.items():
            print x, y 
            #print '\n'
        #print 'select one\n'
        print '\n'
        try:
            self.choice = int(raw_input("Enter choice :"))
        except:
            print("No valid integer! Please try  ...")
            self.main()
        self.check()

```
def check(self):
    #print 'select one\n'
    if self.choice == 1:
        self.genpass()  
    elif self.choice == 3:
        self.exi(exit)
    else:
        print 'invalid entry try again' 
        self.main()
        #print 'invalid'

def genpass(self):
    import random
    import re
    import string 
    min_len = 8
    max_len = 12
    self.passlen = random.randint(min_len, max_len)
    #s = "@4A%1aXb6!B2#8lZ$t5&"
    #random.shuffle(s)
    #password =  "".join(random.sample(s,passlen))
    #print 'Generate password \n', password, '\n'

    self.password1 = ""
    SpecialChars = "!@#$%%^*"
    self.password1 += random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase)
    self.password1 += random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
    self.password1 += random.choice(string.digits)
    self.password1 += random.choice(SpecialChars)
    for i in range(0,self.passlen):
        self.password1 += random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase +
          string.ascii_lowercase + 
          string.digits+
          SpecialChars)
    self.all_symbol = ''.join(random.sample(self.password1,self.passlen))
    flag =0
    while True:   
        if not re.search("[a-z]", self.all_symbol): 
            flag = -1
            break
        elif not re.search("[A-Z]", self.all_symbol): 
            flag = -1
            break
        elif not re.search("[0-9]", self.all_symbol): 
            flag = -1
            break
        elif not re.search("[_@$]", self.all_symbol): 
            flag = -1
            break
        elif re.search("\s", self.all_symbol): 
            flag = -1
            break
        else: 
            flag = 0
            print 'password Length\t', self.passlen
            print 'Generate password is\t', self.all_symbol, '\n'
            break

    if flag ==-1: 
        self.genpass()




        #print len(password)
def exi(self, exit):
    import sys
    sys.exit()
```

while True:
    p=password()
    p.main()